# Duplicate tags torah reading/sevice

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Why do we have a [torah-service](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-service) tag and a [torah-reading](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-reading) tag? Is there a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I've tagged things [torah-service](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-service) if they were about *hagbaha* (raising the scroll before or after the reading), removing the scroll from its cabinet, *mi sheberach* prayers said around the time of the reading, or the like, and [torah-reading](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-reading) if they were about the reading or the blessings said for the reading. That *seems* to be their use by others also. Perhaps the split is a good one, but the tags need better wikis?

Comment: That's how I think of those tags as well. The two have a large area of overlap (the actual reading in the synagogue), but each has its own other areas (hagbaha, etc. for the former; practicing reading, etc. for the latter)

Comment: I added to the tag wikis.  They could probably use more attention.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, nicely done; thanks.